# Parity/Mist syncing problem

Tags: mist, synchronization, parity

I tried a few things and after a few attempts and ~24 hours the chain was synced. One thing i tried was to sync my PC clock after "time.is". It always showed a delay. I downloaded a program which promised to sync the clock and it actually did. "time.is" showed me that my clock works right. Also my full node is working. the only strange thing is, everytime when i open Mist i get this popup message first

: [image]

Do you know why?